# Using Loop Conditions in Excel-Ruby Watir Scripts

Tags: ruby, loops

I'm New to Ruby-Watir ..And am Checking Login Functionality for one Application that Multiple values like (Invalid user& Password ,Valid Username & Password)coming from Excel Sheet.

```
reqire'watir-webdriver'
require 'win32ole'
require 'roo'

b = Watir::Browser.new

b.goto 'http://tech/mellingcarsweb/Admin/Login.aspx'

xl = WIN32OLE.new('excel.application')

wrkbook= xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Excel\\cars.xlsx")

wrksheet= wrkbook.Worksheets(1)

wrksheet.select

$username= wrksheet.Range("A1").Value

$password= wrksheet.Range("B1").Value

b.text_field(:id, "MainContent_txtUsername").set($username)


b.text_field(:id, "MainContent_txtPassword").set($password)


b.button(:id, "MainContent_btnLogin").click

b.alert.ok

$username1= wrksheet.Range("A2").Value

$password1= wrksheet.Range("B2").Value

b.text_field(:id, "MainContent_txtUsername").set($username1)


b.text_field(:id, "MainContent_txtPassword").set($password1)


b.button(:id, "MainContent_btnLogin").click

puts "Authorised Entry"
```

This code is working fine.What my need is.. **using loop statements i need to  execute for  multiple times.**

I don't Know how to use looping conditions in Excel.And i have seen lot of Examples But none of them are clear.Sorry am not able to  understand.Will anyone Explain me in proper way of using looping Conditions in Excel ruby.

Thanks

Comment: If you only want something simple, this is not a good place to get it. This is a good place to solve complex problems. Otherwise you are saying "I don't want to invest any effort into solving this, you other volunteers must do it for me." Not a good message, IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you are testing valid and invalid logins, I am not sure that it makes the most sense to write a loop. The problem with a loop is that, each iteration needs to know what the expected result is. You would likely need to include that information in your spreadsheet. You might be better off creating specific individual tests for each valid and invalid scenario (ie one assertion per test).

To answer your question, you can convert the excel range to a 2D array and then iterate through each row of data. To get the 2D array:

```
require 'win32ole'

#Open the spreadsheet
xl = WIN32OLE.new('excel.application')
wrkbook= xl.Workbooks.Open('C:\Users\Someone\Desktop\Logins.xlsx')
wrksheet= wrkbook.Worksheets(1)

#Convert the range of cells to a 2D array
login_data = wrksheet.range("A1:B2").value

#Output of the 2D array
p login_data
#=> [["jsmith", "password1"], ["jdoe", "password2"]]
```

Each element of the 2D array is a row of the excel data. You can iterate through it using the `each` method.

```
#Start your browser
b = Watir::Browser.new    

#Loop through the login data
login_data.each do |data|

    #Determine the user id and password for the row of data
    user = data[0]
    password = data[1]

    #Go to the login page
    b.goto 'http://tech/mellingcarsweb/Admin/Login.aspx'

    #Input the fields and submit
    b.text_field(:id, "MainContent_txtUsername").set(user)
    b.text_field(:id, "MainContent_txtPassword").set(password)
    b.button(:id, "MainContent_btnLogin").click

    #Do something to validate the result
end
```

Comment: Thanks Justin For Your Help ..While Entering Wrong Input Alertbox Appears..And i used this code ----------------------------------- if b.alert.text.include?("Invalid UserName And Password")

    b.alert.ok

  else

       puts "Not Found"

  end    After enering into the Application Getting Error like in `rescue in assert_exists': unable to locate alert (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)..Any Idea

Comment: Is it failing on the scenario where the alert does not appear (I assume a successful login)? You probably want an if condition to check if the alert exists - `b.alert.exists?`

Comment: Thanks Justin Everthing Works fine..First of all I don't know how to ask this question..But u catched the ques which is in  my mind..Great Work..

Answer (score 0):

Google for `ruby loops`. This looks like a good introduction: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_loops.htm

Comment: I just want to run above of my code using [for loop statements].Plz Explain me in a Simpler Way...

Comment: After long Struggle learned and Executed Still Problems come will anyone give me solution:

Comment: You will have to prove that you actually did something. Share the code that you have tried.

Comment: After learned  Still Problem rises will anyone give me solution:wrksheet.range("A1:A2").each {

   |cell|

   $username = cell.value

 }

  wrksheet.range("B1:B2").each {

      |cell|

   $password = cell.value

 }
b.text_field(:id, "MainContent_txtUsername").set($username)

b.text_field(:id, "MainContent_txtPassword").set($password)

b.button(:id, "MainContent_btnLogin").click

b.alert.ok
what my problem is above code  getting the second value(A2:B2)from excel not getting the first value ..Kindly provide any Idea

Comment: Hi Zelijko i have shared tat code wat i have tried Kindly provide some Guidance..